# JQuery, find out what's visible and hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JQuery does this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#settings_button').click(function(){ 

if ($('div#edit_profile:visible'))
{
$('#edit_profile').fadeOut(function() {$('#account_settings').fadeIn();});
}
else if ($('div#leave:visible'))
{
$('#leave').fadeOut(function() {$('#account_settings').fadeIn();});
}
}); 



$('#edit_button').click(function(){ 

if($('div#account_settings:visible'))
{
$('#account_settings').fadeOut(function() {$('#edit_profile').fadeIn();});
}
else if ($('div#leave:visible'))
{
$('#leave').fadeOut(function() {$('#edit_profile').fadeIn();});
}

}); 


});
```

This kind of works, just, although the "leave" div is visable, it won't hide it. How do I detect if it's visable and then if it is, it fades it out. I tried it the way about, doesn't seem to work. What's the best way of doing this? I hope I explained it well enough.
-Sal

**Edit, I found my answer:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#settings_button').click(function(){ 

if ($('div#edit_profile').is(':visible'))
{
$('#edit_profile').fadeOut(function() {$('#account_settings').fadeIn();});
}
else if ($('div#leave').is(':visible'))
{
$('#leave').fadeOut(function() {$('#account_settings').fadeIn();});
}
}); 



$('#edit_button').click(function(){ 

if($('div#account_settings').is(':visible'))
{
$('#account_settings').fadeOut(function() {$('#edit_profile').fadeIn();});
}
else if ($('div#leave').is(':visible'))
{
$('#leave').fadeOut(function() {$('#edit_profile').fadeIn();});
}

}); 


});
```

Comment: WAIT! I'm an IDIOT! I need to use: ($('div#edit_profile').is(':visible'))

Comment: if that was your solution, you can post it as an answer

Comment: it won't let me :( I have less than 100 rep so i can;t answer for 8 hours. the answer was if($('div#account_settings').is(':visible')) i had to use the is() function.

Comment: Sorry to have wasted time. :(

Comment: :) Its never a waste of time if it could help someone else. Did not know about the [8 hour limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89063/answering-own-question-now-has-8-hour-limit) Come back after 8 hours or so. Good job on editing the post and posting your answer there.

Comment: @Silas: Do you always write code without any indentation? It makes it extremely hard to read! Besides that, please post your answer as an answer instead of editing it into your question!

Comment: As a note, if you're identifying a specific element via its ID, don't use a tag selector before it (`$('div#edit_profile')` for example). If you specify the tag first, jQuery will look for all elements that match that tag, then look through those to see if the ID matches the next part of the selector, rather than using the much faster `document.getElementById()` provided by the browser.

Comment: @ThiefMaster there is an [8 hour limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89063/answering-own-question-now-has-8-hour-limit) for him.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Are you sure it doesn't use getElementById and then performs a tagName check?

Comment: According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) it does use getElementById first, then performs "additional checks", which would be the tagName check in this case

Answer (score 0):

As you already recognized, you want the `.is(':visible')` notation. I just wanted to chime in that this is a perfect opportunity for you to extract a function:

```
function toggleIfVisible(hide, show) {
    var $hide = $(hide);
    if($hide.is(':visible')) {
        $hide.fadeOut(function() { $(show).fadeIn() });
    }
}

toggleIfVisible('#edit_profile', '#account_settings');
```

**EDIT:** When you have done that, you could even make it a jQuery method:

```
$.fn.hideAndShow = function(other) {
    if(this.is(':visible')) {
        this.fadeOut(function() { $(other).fadeIn() });
    }
}

$("#edit_profile").hideAndShow("#account_settings");
```